# How to prevent automatic conversion when passing argument to property?

Tags: vba

Why it does not fail when I try to pass string (`testString = "10"`) argument to property which takes currency parameter (`ByVal newCash as Currency`)? I do not want this automatic conversion. How to prevent it? How to disable it?

`Model` class module

```
Option Explicit

Private m_cash As Currency

Public Property Let Cash(ByVal newCash As Currency)
    m_cash = newCash
End Property
```

`Test` class module

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim modelObj as Model
    Dim testString as String

    Set modelObj = New Model
    testString = "10"

    modelObj.Cash = testString
End Sub
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is be aware of [**reserved words**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90)).  Don't use words like `module` and `value` as the name of a variable.  Don't you think `Dim module as module` could be a little confusing?  Secondly, it's very unclear what you're trying to do here.  I'd suggest you put `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [forever] so help with name conflicts, and then you'll need to share more background and examples of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ashleedawg I've changed `module` to `model`, `value` is not reserved word, but I've changed it to `cash`. I want to get error when I try to set `m_cash As Currency` via `testString as String`.

Comment: You could check the type and raise your own `Sub test(x As Variant)

If TypeName(x) <> "Long" Or TypeName(x) <> "Integer" Then
    Err.Raise 9999, , "Incorrect"
End If

End Sub`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav if I do `Property Let(ByVal newCash As Variant)` then I have to do `Property Get Value() As Variant` also. I do not want to return from getter `As Variant`.

Comment: You can return it as a conversion, the variable added will be correct, so your get doesn't need to change

Comment: VBA will always try to force a data type to "fit", if it possibly can - it's not C#, more like JavaScript in this respect (I'm assuming you come from another programming language since you expect stronger data typing). If Nathan's suggestion is not helpful, then you need to build type-checking into the code that sends data to your class/properties. Possibly a function that checks data types.  Or force a conversion (`val = CCur(testString)`) - which would trigger an error if the conversion is not possible - before sending `val` to `modelObj.Cash`.